# No OpenCL platform detected

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, opencl

Ive tried dozens of methods, driver installs, uninstalls, reboots, reloads and all with the same result "no open cl platforms detected" as per below... really about to throw the towel in on this...

Team Red Miner version 0.8.3
[2021-06-28 19:20:52] Pool eu1.ethermine.org: Ethermine ethash auto mode detected, setting --eth_stratum=ethproxy
[2021-06-28 19:20:52] No AMD OpenCL platforms detected.
[2021-06-28 19:20:52] Successful clean shutdown.

The GPU is a new RX5500XT, yes, i know its 4Gb, oversight on my part being new to this but just cant understand why i keep getting this error, any further info needed please ask as i don't want to post a bunch of reading material here for no reason...

Thanks :)

Comment: read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: I also see this with an AMD RX 570/570X 8 GB. On Zorin OS 16. teamredminer-v0.8.6.2-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can find out which drivers you're using by running `lshw -c video | grep driver`. If you are using Mesa drivers, which are used by default, OpenCL is not yet supported for newer GPUs. AMD's website contains drivers for these newer GPUs, and as far as I know, they support OpenCL on all of their drivers. For example, here is the link to 5500 XT drivers. https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-xt

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong command in the post. I meant `lshw -c video | grep driver`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the response all the command returns is as follows...  configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1280x720 visual=truecolor xres=1280 yres=720

Comment: Hi, This is all the info i get back...

Number of platforms                               2
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (3275.0)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD

Comment: Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-7048a15 2021-06-30 focal-oibaf-ppa)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA
 Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0

Comment: Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Radeon RX 5500 XT (NAVI14, DRM 3.41.0, 5.8.0-59-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 21.2.0-devel 
(git-7048a15 2021-06-30 focal-oibaf-ppa)
  Driver Version                                  21.2.0-devel
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1

Comment: Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Device Available                                Yes
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Max compute units                               22
  Max clock frequency                             1900MHz
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256

Comment: === CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ===
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local//usr/lib/clc/gfx1012-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory
  Preferred work group size multiple              <getWGsizes:1200: create kernel : error -46>
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2

Comment: half                                                 0 / 0        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    I

Comment: nfinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)

Comment: Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              8309002240 (7.738GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No

Comment: Max memory allocation                           3435973836 (3.2GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   No
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max number of constant args                     16

Comment: Max constant buffer size                        67108864 (64MiB)
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No

Comment: Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_extended_versioning

Comment: NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              Success [MESA]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform

Comment: clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the information overload, did not know what else to put here :( i am very new to this, still learning :)

Comment: Annndddd still no luck...

owl182@owl182-BTC-T37:~/Downloads/teamredminer-v0.8.3-linux$ sudo ./run_autotune_quick.sh
[sudo] password for owl182: 
          Team Red Miner version 0.8.3
[2021-06-30 18:24:05] No AMD OpenCL platforms detected.
[2021-06-30 18:24:05] Successful clean shutdown.
owl182@owl182-BTC-T37:~/Downloads/teamredminer-v0.8.3-linux$

Comment: You are using Mesa drivers, judging from the clinfo output. You should download the AMD drivers for the 5500XT from AMD's website: https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-series/amd-radeon-rx-5500-xt

Comment: I am not quite sure if the new drivers replace the old ones automatically, but I would assume it does.

Comment: Thank you, i will try :)

Comment: Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu_21.20-1271047_amd64.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-core_21.20-1271047_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-dkms_5.11.5.26-1271047_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.11.5.26-1271047_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-doc_21.20-1271047_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-install
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-lib_21.20-1271047_amd64.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-lib32_21.20-1271047_amd64.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pin_21.20-1271047_all.deb

Comment: E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-install
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-lib32_21.20-1271047_amd64.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-pin_21.20-1271047_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl_21.20-1271047_amd64.deb
owl182@owl182-BTC-T37:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-21.20-1271047-ubuntu-20.04$ 

And so it continues...

Comment: Did you run the driver installation by doing ./amdgpu-pro-install or ./amdgpu-install in the driver folder that you downloaded? If not, what did you run?

Comment: Hi, I ran install from the driver forder as you suggested above :)

Comment: Unpacking amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.11.5.26-1271047) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.11.5.26-1271047_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/amdgpu-dkms-firmware/LICENSE', which is also in package rock-dkms-firmware 1:4.2-21
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.11.5.26-1271047_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Looks like i broke something...

Comment: So currently, rocm is installed, which uses similar files to the AMDGPU driver. I would suggest removing rocm by doing `sudo apt remove rocm-dkms` and then run `amdgpu-uninstall` to remove all of the broken installation files. Then run the driver install again and it should work.

Comment: Morning :) I shall try that, did you see my other question ? perhaps if i can repair what it is giving an error for then uninstall wotn be needed... i am not at that machine during the day though, only nights and weekends :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the AMDGPU driver does not install and throws errors when it isn't properly uninstalled before. In this case, the easiest repair to your issue is to uninstall rocm and the amdgpu driver, and then install the amdgpu driver again.